# Using Office 365 as a file server

Tags: c#, asp.net, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET application to access files store on a Office 365 sharepoint site. The files are public and anybody can download them. I look at the Office 365 api but from what I can tell, you need to be able to login before the application can call the api.

Is there no way to set the credential in the web config and make it so that the application can get the file for everybody? Since the files are public, most users will not have an account.

Answer (score 1):

I cant be categorical, but Office 365 uses Federated Identity which requires a user to be present; you dont pass credentials to it - you pass a callback "pointer" URL which it calls you back with. The user types their credentials into Office 365 not into your application - so you cant pass credentials to Office 365/OneDrive.

Comment: I see, so is there something else I can use to allow public access to files on a sharepoint site?